# How to get assertion results in ant reports for JMeter test plan

Tags: ant, jmeter

I am running JMeter tests using Ant(ant -Dtest=JMeterTestPlan). Tests is getting executed however response assertions are not coming in HTML report though test has failed.How do I get response assertions in HTML report,I am able to see assertion results in JMeter GUI but not in Ant
For ex:I have used OS sampler to check if a process is running and I am expecting the return code to be 0,Also I have used Response assertion to display custom error message that the process is not running
In Ant report I am only getting results for OS sampler that the expected value is not found,also there is no Assertion results in html report(Main intention of me using Assertion results is to display custom error message that the process is not running in report)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your issue using latest [JMeter 5.1.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-1-1-released-td5728320.html)

- [OS Process Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) snapshot:

  [image]
- [Response Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-assertions-in-jmeter-32-new-and-improved/) Snapshot

  [image]
- [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener output:

  [image]
- Ant HTML report:

  [image]

Ant's [`build.xml`](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/v5_1_1/extras/build.xml) and [`jmeter-results-detail-report_21.xsl`](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/v5_1_1/extras/jmeter-results-detail-report_21.xsl) are not changed

Comment: Thansk for your help,I reinstalled JMETER and the issue is not seen.Maybe I might have done some misconfiguration in build.xml. Is it possible to merge the html reports of different tests that are run seperately into single one.I know about aggregate report.The problem here is same test plan is run in different systems,is it possible to merge all to give a single result

Comment: There is [Merge Results](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/MergeResults/) plugin which can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/) which can be used for combining up to 4 result files into a single one. It is possible to combine more, however you will need to run the merge several times

Comment: Thanks again for your help,I will use this